# mysql лог больших ответов на запросы

Tags: mysql, логирование

Проблема в том что постоянно идут запросы с большими выборками что загружает исходящий канал mysql сервера.

Лог медленных запросов не даёт точной картины т.к. сервер ещё не перегружен и справляется с нагрузкой.

Есть ли способ отследить именно большие выборки и логировать их?

Comment: Можно проверить каждую выборку, используйте EXPLAIN, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: *Есть ли способ отследить именно большие выборки и логировать их?* Включите General Log и логируйте сами запросы. Там видно, кто и какие запросы выполняет. Повторив их, можно приблизительно узнать объём выборки (можно обернуть в `SELECT COUNT()`, если интересует только количество записей).

Comment: общий лог запросов не даёт той информативности как в mysql-slow и в нём придётся все запросы прогонять руками